# How to use Rewarded Video ads using admob on android studio

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I still don't find any answer to my concerns. 
I followed Step by step the tutorial made available by google at this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video
I added 3 mediation networks:

- AppLovin
- ChartBoost
- Unity Ads

When I run the code I got this error: onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad.
Please if you can send me an example app where you correctly implement rewarded video it will be very helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that now you have to achive some minimum amonut views from the other networks. I mean, Google Team have to know that you really use the service in other networks. The only solution I've found is that to integrate any of yours rewarded networks in release. And then integrate your Admob Rewarded Video in the project. I've tried to do the same thing 3 monthes ago and faced the same issue.

Or try to wait 3-4 days. It might they've fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/AppLovin/Android-SDK-Demo/blob/master/AppLovin-Android-Demo-App/src/main/java/com/applovin/demoapp/rewarded/RewardedVideosActivity.java) AppLovin's rewarded video example if you want to integrate just them. I've found that they generally have better CPMs than that of other ad networks.

Comment: I already used this example and it worked just fine, but what I want to do is using Admob Mediation to show Video Ads from Applovin or other networks. Any examples about that?

Comment: [Here](https://www.applovin.com/integration#adMobIntegration) is their AdMob integration instructions.